# Count values in time ranges (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**I am trying to make a sql query in which I want to count the people comprised in three ranges:**

```
Tomorrow (from 06:00 a.m. to 12:00 p.m.)
Afternoon (from 12:00 p.m. to 9:00 p.m.)
Night (from 9:00 p.m. to 6:00 a.m.)
```

I have two attributes, check in time and check out time which have the following format:

```
2020-05-20 12:10:29.000
```

I am doing it in the following way but it does not work, for example, in the night:

```
select (case when datepart(hour, dateIn) > datepart(hour, '21')) and
                  datepart(minute, dateIn) > datepart(minute, '00'))
```

Comment: you should provide sample data, and show what result you want

Comment: Why not just `WHERE DateIn >= '06:00:00' AND DateIn <= '12:00:00'`, considering you suggest your column is the `time` datatype?

Comment: @Larnu sorry, I've updated the post, my datatime is like this 2020-05-20 12:10:29.000

Comment: My data is like this 2020-05-20 12:10:29.000 @JimmyN sorry, i forgot it

Comment: Are you always after values for tomorrow?

Comment: @Larnu I have values from differents days

Comment: Then we really need that sample data and expected results, @greatWallace . We're clearly missing information here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can subtract 6 hours to get the date and then use time comparisons for the shift.  So, I think you want:

```
select convert(date, dateadd(hour, -6, t.datein)), v.shift, count(*)
from t cross apply
     (values (case when convert(time, t.datein) < '06:00:00' then 'night'
                   when convert(time, t.datein) < '12:00:00' then 'morning'
                   when convert(time, t.datein) < '21:00:00' then 'afternoon'
                   else 'night'
              end)
     ) v(shift)
group by convert(date, dateadd(hour, -6, datein)), v.shift;
```